# Multiple main-methods for testing purposes in Netbeans 7.4 (project from Netbeans 7.2.1)

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, program-entry-point

I recently switched from my older Netbeans version 7.2.1 to 7.4. I am working on a bigger project which uses only one main-entry point of course. However, for testing purposes I am using a second class which also contains a main-method. In my older Netbeans version I was able to Shift+F6 (Run File) and it did what it says: It runs the file because if has a valid main-method. With the never version of the IDE the program keeps telling me, that there is no `main`-method. This main-method is anything but special and the autocheck does not warn me either (Why wouldn't it? It is totally valid and worked in version 7.2.1).

Here is my testing class definition for the sake of completeness:

```
package Tests;

// various imports from surrounding project or external packages

public class TEST001 {

    // variables and methods for further testing

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // [...]
    }

}
```

---

1. Now, are there **incompabilities** between projects of Netbeans 7.2.1 to these of version 7.4 which might have caused this?
2. Or do I have to **check a special option** somewhere to allow the handling of multiple main-entry points? Which seems unlikely because running a file instead of the project seems to be permanent feature with its own user controls.
3. Or is this simply a **bug**?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you try running the file using the context menu of your source file? If that works, maybe a different file in the project explorer had the focus?

Comment: I rather think it's a bug/technical issue with the installation. Now, after a restart, Netbeans isn't even able to load its own modules and older projects are unaccessible (marked as "broken").